# unit test Spring boot service class that has dependency on another service class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mocking

I am writing up a spring boot rest service in which am trying to unit test a class annotated with @Service.
This service class internally uses another service class.
Here is the code :

```
@Service
public class TieredClaimServiceImpl implements TieredClaimService {

//this is the second service used within 
// commented out setter injection and used constructor injection 
// @Autowired
private DiscountTierService discountTierService;

@Autowired
public TieredClaimServiceImpl(MerchRepository merchRepository,SalesRepository 
         salesRepository,DiscountTierService discountTierService) {
    this.merchRepository = merchRepository;
    this.salesRepository = salesRepository;
    this.discountTierService = discountTierService;
}
```

Here is the method within the class that I would need to unit test :

```
@Override
public List <TieredClaimDto>  calculateClaim(ClaimRequestDto claimRequestDto,String xAppCorelationId) throws SystemException {

    /** get the discount tier config data  - this is where we are using the other service **/
    List<DiscountTierDto> discountTierList = discountTierService.get();
```

I would like to mock the 'DiscountTierService' used within 'TieredClaimServiceImpl'

In my unit test class I tried to mock the call being made to this service :

```
DiscountTierService discountTierService = mock(DiscountTierService.class);
```

OR

```
DiscountTierService discountTierService = spy(new DiscountTierServiceImpl());
```

Neither of these worked .

Though not directly related I had a question related to this entire solutioning [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59102896/spring-boot-which-slice-to-use-for-testing-service-component)

Comment: how does your unit test look like? How are you creating `TieredClaimServiceImpl`  --are you booting up whole spring context to create them as beans, or do you do it manually without context using `new`?

Comment: Mocking is the appropriate tool here. Please explain "didn't work".

Answer (score 2):

You are saying about unit tests but trying to create the integration test

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfules(value = "test")//or @TestPropertySource(s)
@RunWith(value = SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SomeTestConfiguration.class})
public class SomeTestClass {

    @Autowired//or @Mock
    private MerchRepository merchRepository;

    @Autowired//or @Mock
    private SalesRepository salesRepository;

    @Mock
    private DiscountTierService discountTierService;

    private TieredClaimService service;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        service = new TieredClaimServiceImpl(merchRepository, salesRepository, discountTierService);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        //arrange
        var dto1 = new DiscountTierDto(...);
        var dto2 = new DiscountTierDto(...);
        var someList = List.of(dto1, dto2);
        when(discountTierService.get()).thenReturn(someList);
        //act
        service.calculateClaim(someClaimRequestDto, someAppCorrelationId);
        //assert
        Assert.assertThat(...);
    }
}
```

If you want really to create a unit test, you don't need most class annotations, just @RunWith, and set test properties if necessary (of course, in this case, you cannot autowire repositories, just mock).

But if you are looking on the integration test where you will call a controller method which calls the service, you need to create MockMvc object with a standalone controller. And creating the controller object just set this service configuration - in this case, you can control all required nested objects (service, nested service, repositories).